# UNABLE_TO_LOCK_ROW, unable to obtain exclusive access to this record(For Email To Case bulk creation)

Tags: apex, exception, email2case

I have read all the previous question that was asked with the same subject in Stack exchange, However I could not find solution that fit me.

We have a bulk E2C created from a third part system named (Workday ERP system)
it creates E2C in a bulk however it get interrupted in between and remaining were getting failed.

Please advise if there is any solution has found for this.

Comment: You need to optimize in such a way that the code would not process any (DMl ) record which is already locked for editing. So its trying to wait for the record to get it released and fail when the timeout value reached with the message "UNABLE_TO_LOCK_ROW".

Comment: @bharath There is our challenge we are not getting due to which Class/Trigger the error is Throwing as the Error Code is very Straight "UNABLE_TO_LOCK_ROW, unable to obtain exclusive access to this record" No specific line of code involved. Hence we were not in position to Identify Due to Which trigger it throws error